# How to call a bamboo branch instead of master from GitHub using the powershell script task

Tags: powershell, github, bamboo

I am currently getting the repository for a GitHub project called Devops and it is getting the master.  But now I want to get the branch instead of the master which it is getting by default but I don't know how to do it from the powershell script.  This is how it is done for the master branch.

```
cd ${bamboo.build.working.directory}
if [ -d devops ] ; then
cd devops 2>/dev/null && git pull || git clone https://MYGIT:myGIT@github.com/myRepo/devops
else
git clone https://MYGIT:myGIT@github.com/myRepo/devops
fi
```

I tried to add .branchname, /branchname, -branchname etc to the end of it but it didn't find the branch, how can I find the branch instead of the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by doing this:

```
git clone -b BRANCH_NAME https://MYGIT:myGIT@github.com/myRepo/devops
```

for the else part and then in the if statement I did this:

```
# Get the current branch
function gitBranchName {
    $currentBranch = "master"
    git branch | foreach {
        if ($_ -match "<branch_name>") {
            $currentBranch = "<branch_name>"
        }
    }
    return $currentBranch
}
```